# PHP magento cookie encryption

Tags: php, magento, cookies, encryption

I want to set a cookie with but encrypt the information and decrypt when retrieving.  Are there any Magento classes I can use?

I am running Magento 1.4.1.1 and I am setting my cookies with:

```
 Mage::getModel('core/cookie')->set($name, $value, $period, $path, $domain, $secure, $httponly);
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: a cookie is not a safe place for storage of sensitive data, encrypted or not, put it in your data base.

Comment: Dagon, thanks!!! duly noted... would you be willing to elaborate on the potential problems this may cause.

Comment: The only thing that should ever be stored in  a cookie is a session id.

Comment: ah... good call!! Thanks Dagon.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In Magento, you can encrypt the data using:

```
Mage::getModel('core/encryption')->encrypt($data);
```

and decrypt using:

```
Mage::getModel('core/encryption')->decrypt($data);
```

Comment: MagePsycho... Thanks brother, that did it!!