# How to decrypt magento 'frontend' cookies?

Tags: php, magento, cookies, encryption

I have a custom frontend page, and the layout of the page changes depending if you are a fresh new customer, or if you already are a customer.

My idea is to use the cookie 'frontend' that magento uses to know if you are login or logout. But the value of this cookie is encrypted (ex: 4u085d9rakllvg5jqadj2qm0f7).

So my problem is that I can't find how to decrypt the decrypted value of the cookie. I tried to use `Mage::getModel('core/encryption')->decrypt($data);` (as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11834689/php-magento-cookie-encryption)). But the value returned is not readable.

My question is: Do you know how to use the 'frontend' cookie set by magento?

Best.

Comment: A session ID is a randomly generated string, are you sure that there's actual content?

Comment: How magento know if you are connected or not with this value?

Comment: What code you have used to initialize $data.

Comment: It creates a session file in var/sessions and keys to the cookie. Browser/server interchange exchanges the session cookie which allows Magento to store information in the session file.

Comment: @SatishMantri. I used the value from $_COOKIE['frontend']

Comment: use $customerData = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomer(); to check the customer data ... you just cannot read and act on cookie data